# Request handler slows when parent forks a long-running child process in Node

Tags: node.js, express, child-process, spawn

I am off-loading some processing in the Express request-response cycle by forking a process using the node child-process module.  I basically have the following code in a Express middleware:

```
forkedProcess = child.fork(scriptFile);
forkedProcess.send(messageToChild);
forkedProcess.on('message',function(messageFromChild) {...});
```

Then in the child process, I have:

```
process.on('message', function(messageFromParent) {....});
process.send('messageToParent);
process.exit(0);
```

While testing, I decided to insert some dummy statements to keep the child process running for long so that I can send another request to the parent in the interim. The problem is that the second request takes a long time to respond. The request handler itself does not start for a few seconds on the second request.

I am unable to understand why? A child process should not block the parent main event loop and apparently does not because the second request does get handled before the child process of the first request exits but it takes a long time. If I take the dummy statements from the child process, the request-response cycle works normally. I simulated the test case because the child forked processes are generated dynamically based upon some developer scripts. These developer scripts  should not slow the main loop... apparently it does. WHY?

Comment: You fork a child process each time you receive a new request?

Comment: @vineet.hawal Yes I am forking for each request. Each process may be different based upon the request-type though  for the example, I am benchmarking with the same script been forked.  I also tried to send data to the child as a command line argument, rather than through a child.send() and that did not help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forking on each request is not a good idea, considering the cost of time/memory to fork a process itself. Ideally you should fork the required processes on boot and send/receive messages when required.
Hope this helped

Comment: Helpful yes. Upvoted. Got me thinking on the right line but though there are advantages in saving process startup/closing time, are there context/scope conflict issues?  So, the child-process handler will be a app.local variable? And you then, for each request, simply send, receive (on-message) from that process? Your suggestion is very helpful, but does not answer the question because the slowing is NOT due to starting a new child process... it just takes time for the middleware to start which happens much before I fork the new process.

Comment: One more comment... In one case, I have to fork a new process for each request because the script/process is dynamically generated in the middleware... Of course, your suggestion is solid when it comes to a static process which has to handle different requests. Or may be you have some suggestion on how to manage processes which are based upon dynamically generated scripts? The output of these scripts (process.send in the child) is the HTML generated to be read by the main loop, the parent process,  and then gets sent as the HTTP response.